# Norm of an Ideal.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$ and $\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$
How do we describe the ideal $I$ for ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$, given by $I = \{ (2+\alpha) a + (1+ 3 \alpha) b : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and how do we calculate norm of $I.$

I tried writing $I = \{ (2a+b) + (a+ 3b)\alpha : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}\}.$ Now in ring $\mathcal{O}_K/I$ we have $I = 0.$ So $(2a+b) + (a+ 3b)\alpha = 0$ and since $1,\alpha$ are linearly independent we have $2a+b = 0$ and $a+ 3b=0.$ Which gives $a=b=0.$ I dont know what to interpret from this or even I am doing right or wrong. Help please.

Comment: $I$ is an ideal of ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K .$

Comment: Are you sure you've written your ideal correctly? Do you not want $a,b\in \mathcal O_K$?

Comment: I think they are correct. I have proved that this is an ideal using this way. But O dont seems to understand the structure or generators of ideal.

Comment: Not that this matters all that much to your question, but do you know what the golden ratio $\phi$ is? Your use of the letter alpha is bugging me a little bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A useful fact here is that $\mathcal O_K$ is a PID. This means that $I$ can be written in terms of one generator.

As you've written it, $I$ consists of integer combinations of $2+\alpha$ and $1+3\alpha$, so as an ideal, it is generated by these elements. Denote this fact using the notation
$$I = \langle 2+\alpha, 1+3\alpha\rangle.$$

Observe that $$\alpha^2-\alpha -1 = 0$$
and that
$$\alpha(2+\alpha) =2\alpha + \alpha^2 = 2\alpha + (\alpha + 1) = 1+3\alpha.$$

So $I = \langle 2+\alpha\rangle$, and hence the norm of the ideal $I$ will just be the $N_{K/\mathbb Q}(2+\alpha)$.